# How effective was Charlie's fireproof balaclava?

Tags: harry-potter, clothing

Charlie has a fireproof balaclava which he presumably uses as part of his work with dragons.

> Charlie was darning a fireproof balaclava.
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 10, Mayhem at the Ministry)*.</sub>

Balaclavas typically cover the majority of the face but not the eyes. If the purpose of the balaclava was to repel dragon fire then wouldn't it leave the wearer's eyes completely defenceless? How effective could any such balaclava be in protecting someone who works with dragons?

Bear in mind that this isn't even a new balaclava but one which has undergone home-based repairs.

Comment: I assume it was a *magical* balaclava

Comment: @Valorum What good does that do to Charlie's eyes?

Comment: "fireproof: (1) resistant to destruction by fire, (2) totally or almost totally unburnable" - maybe semantics but perhaps it is less about 'repelling' fire than 'not having your face stuck under a burning sack of yarn" - the point about the eyes is valid, but perhaps Charlie, a skilled dragoner, knows enough to at least turn around and shield his eyes or turn around, the balaclava then doesn't catch fire and melt his skull, etc...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would assume that the wearer would also wear [*fireproof goggles* with their balaclava helmet](https://media1.giphy.com/media/L0kuctwC94lt2jbC3F/giphy.gif?cid=790b76115cbde33b4d566c37637838cc). This would afford them fireproof eye protection when close to a dragon but the ability to have free sight when moving away from them. Hermione and the rest of the Hogwarts gang seem familiar with the use of basic [PPE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_LlbHFZUVw) so an experienced dragon trainer like Charlie would also know about it.

> ‘Oh, it was quite fun, really,’ said Hermione, now putting on
> **protective goggles**. ‘I mean, he drones on about famous ex-pupils a
> bit, and he absolutely fawns on McLaggen because he’s so
> well-connected, but he gave us some really nice food and he introduced
> us to Gwenog Jones.’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince — CHAPTER FOURTEEN —
> Felix Felicis</sup></sub>

Alternatively, the clothing may be imbued with some sort of fireproof magic, in the same way that his brothers' Shield Hats protect the wearer from jinxes.

> ‘That’s right … well, we thought Shield Hats were a bit of a laugh.
> You know, challenge your mate to jinx you while wearing it and watch
> his face when the jinx just bounces off. But the Ministry bought five
> hundred for all its support staff! And we’re still getting massive
> orders!’
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince - CHAPTER SIX — Draco’s Detour</sup></sub>